# Is it possible to pass arguments to a (resque-status) Resque::JobWithStatus?

Tags: ruby, backgroundworker, resque

I'm pretty new to resque, but it looks really good for my needs.

Actually, I'm trying to setup a simple test app like:

```
require 'resque'
require 'resque/job_with_status'
class WordAnalyzer < Resque::JobWithStatus
  @queue = "word_analysis"

  def self.perform(word)
    puts "About to do heavy duty analysis on #{word}"
    sleep 3 # fake analysis here
    # this would be something impressive
    puts "Finished with analysis on #{word}"
  end
end
```

And creating a background worker by

```
WordAnalyzer.create(word)
```

Without resque-status, it works perfectly (with calling enqueue instead of creating the worker).
With resque-status, I get a

> wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
>   /.../resque_test/lib/word_analyzer.rb:6:in `perform'
>   /.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/resque-1.16.1/lib/resque/job.rb:127:in `perform'

I've searched both docu and code, but didn't find the proper way of handing arguments to a resque-status job. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh my... I misinterpreted the options hash in the documentation. It works like 

    WordAnalyzer.create(:word => word)

and then accessing 

    options['word'] 

in the instance (not class) method perform.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do

```
WordAnalyzer.create(:word => word)
```

And access that word in perform method by

```
  def perform
    word = options['word']
    puts "About to do heavy duty analysis on #{word}"
    sleep 3 # fake analysis here
    # this would be something impressive
    puts "Finished with analysis on #{word}"
  end
```

Comment: I think because its a symbol and 'word' is a string. If you want to use `options[:word]`, may be you have to do `WordAnalyzer.create(:word => word.to_sym)`. I have not tried it out yet though!